# Gender-neutral "Jane Doe" / "John Doe"

Tags: phrase-requests, gender-neutral

Is there a gender-neutral alternative to "Jane Doe" / "John Doe"?

I would like to provide an example of signed form, but how to avoid using gender when it comes to names? Is there some widely-used idiom for this?

Comment: Would not  "J. Doe"  be a solution?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: @J.Taylor  I agree. And find it appropriate that you would say that. ;) If we use a full name, however, and are coining new ones, something like *Jordan Doe* might work. (Assuming that *Jordan* has not become sufficiently ambiguous.) But that seems a little forced to me. I think that just *J. Doe* is the best choice.

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110169/

Comment: @J.Taylor Thank you for your comment. My only concern on using a "J. Doe" form is it still may refer to male or female, and these options don't apply to all.

Comment: yeah, I guess you would not want a male or female as signatory.....

Comment: @Andrey I don't understand your objection to "J. Doe". Any name (or string of random letters) could still refer to male or female (or any other gender). Doesn't that objection rule out all possible answers?

Comment: I would suggest "Pat Doe".

Comment: ............ Jo Doe?

Comment: John and Jane Doe are not used on forms. Those are terms used by the police or investigating authorities typically in forensic or criminal matters. Now, if a body is a John or Jane Doe, does gender neutral even apply? Dunno. I recently had to survey people re COVID-10 and the form included: Gender=Male, Female, Transgender and Unknown.

Comment: _Jan_ is a common name that can represent either a male or a female (and thus also everything in between). But there's nothing wrong with an initial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A. N. Other**

> Proper noun
>   (British)   A formulaic name that is substituted for that of a person whose name or identity is not known, or not relevant; typically used when exhibiting an example.
>   — [wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/A._N._Other)

Here is an example copied from [freshdesk.com](https://electraform.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/31000135383-uploading-signatures) :

[image: A.N. Other]

And a similar definition from  [macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/a-n-other) :

> a member of a sports team who has not been chosen yet, so that you cannot give their real name in a list of players

Comment: Strange, I had not heard of this one. But *A.N* sounds too much like the feminine *Ann* to me. Even if it is used, it's an unfortunately *poor* choice, which doesn't actually connote gender neutrality at all.

Comment: @JasonBassford I have heard this often, but maybe it is a British expression (as stated in wiktionary.org).

Comment: It is gender neutral. The "A" and the "N" are sounded out separately. I don't think anyone (well in Britain/Ireland at least) would interpret it as Anne.

Comment: I have no reason to doubt it may be common in Britain—and may be used to express neutrality. But I still think its pronunciation (of a woman's name) makes it a poor choice. In the image you attached, there are no periods used—it would be pronounced as that dictionary word. But perhaps (bizarrely to me), everybody simply knows to say the words separate in that specific context . . .

Comment: The female name is spelt "Ann" or "Anne" not AN. So it should be obvious.

Comment: If you read this, how does A. N. get read as Ann?? It doesn't. Like any initials, you say the letters, you aren't reading words.

Comment: You can't sign the form A.N. whatever. The actual signature does not change.

Comment: @JasonBassford How does /eɪ/. /ɛn/. /ˈʌðə/, sound like "Anne"? -- OED: **A. N. Other**, n. **A formula substituted for: (the name of) an (additional) unidentified or as yet unspecified person or party.** 1884   Manitoba Daily Free Press *Canada..forwards, B. Chambers, W. Cameron, H. Cameron, Hunt, Mulvey, A. N. Other.* -- 1929   Charleston (W. Va.) Gaz. *Baron Renfrew was billed in the Founders Cup Golf Tournament list here as Mr A. N. Other.*

Answer (score 3):

The most fitting name to me for non-binary is "Jay Doe."  It is important not just to use the letter. The problem is that the letter J is used genericly for a person of unknown sex or gender and could become confusing when heard (J and Jay sound the same).

Answer (score 0):

How about Jo Doe as a gender neutral name?

Comment: This would benefit from a citation or authoritative source.  Please see the [help] and site [tour].

Answer (score -1):

*Lorem J. Ipsum* is a familiar pair of words that will at least get you a few smiles.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum